# Quadcopter one beep and blink problem

Tags: control, quadcopter

I have just built my first quadcopter, and have run into a bit of a snag. When I plug in the power, I only get one beep and a red blink from the [flight control board](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__21977__hobbyking_multi_rotor_control_board_v3_0_atmega328_pa_.html), and nothing else happens. When I turn on the controller, however, a red light turns on on the reciever. Otherwise, nothing else happens. From what I can tell, I have plugged in everything correctly, and am not sure how to proceed.

- [flight control board](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__21977__hobbyking_multi_rotor_control_board_v3_0_atmega328_pa_.html)
- [Flight Control Board manual (PDF)](http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uploads/116867307X7478X23.pdf)
- [ESC's](https://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__25365__Turnigy_Multistar_30_Amp_Multi_rotor_Brushless_ESC_2_4S.html)

I do not have a connection from the power distribution board to the flight control board, because I am assuming that it gets its power from the ESC's.

Here is [the video I used to figure out how to build a quad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csnYH_eq-Xk).  (side- note about the video: I have not cut the ESC's cords as done in the guide, seemed like a silly step, also I have seen other applications where they were not cut)

I have not updated the firmware on the board, i have put it in out of the box

[here](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uploads/116867307X7478X23.pdf) is the board's user manual (PDF)

Comment: You should start with the manual for the flight control board.  Is it available online?

Comment: The hobby king page for it says that one exists, but I have not been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: EDIT: I have found the manual and it does not provide any troubleshooting help

Comment: Can you post the link to the manual you found?

Comment: here, it's a PDF
http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uploads/116867307X7478X23.pdf